# Find the longest path between any two nodes

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I have a binary tree. I need to write Java recursive method that will give longest path between two nodes.

For example longest path if following tree is 7 (7-8-5-13-15-18-16-17).

http://img294.imageshack.us/img294/130/treeb.jpg

What's the way to resolve this problem?

(The method: public static int longestPath(Node n) )

Comment: Please post whatever code you have written so far and we will help.  However, I (for one) am not going to give you a solution.  It would defeat the purpose of your homework ... which is to get you to learn to write programs for yourself.

Comment: You could find some help more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664390/how-to-create-a-linked-list-of-nodes-that-are-contained-in-the-max-depth-of-a-bin

Answer (score 1):

Considering this is homework I'd look at [Depth-First search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and [Breadth-First search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

With a preference for depth-first

Comment: great!! Though it was hard to figure out at the first instance!

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you can write a function that returns the height of the tree, which is equal to the length of the longest path.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clue:

First, can you solve this simpler problem?

Find the max from a list of integers.

Second, a new path occurs whenever a node has children.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that the [problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) is NP-complete, so you *probably* won't be able to find a polynomial algorithm.

Comment: Nope. Read the article: for acyclic graph it's P. A tree is acyclic. And this is a comment, at best.